# Remove colons but keep them for post

Tags: regex, perl

I've this string:

> abcd: 1234 **efgh:5678** 90:ijkl

I want to keep word pairs that:

- contains only two words
- delimetered with colons
- starts with alphabetical characters
- ends with numeric characters

I want to replace all other non-matching colons with nothing. The highlighted pair is an example of that I need to match. There is an expected result:

> abcd 1234 **efgh:5678** 90ijkl

Comment: You should edit your question title such as "Remove colons but keep them for post"

Comment: you could use this `:(?=\D)` regex also.

Comment: **amal-murali**, tried other patterns without knowing how it works with trusting in luck, but this not working at all.

**Fede** thanks, 'll do it now.

**avinash-raj**, thanks, 'll try it too!

Comment: @hiprivet You can still improve the quality of this question, and I would recommend that you do.  The question is unclear because you did not describe what differentiates the colon in your bolded text versus the other colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your idea is to keep ports you can use this regex:

```
:(?!\d)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iS5oV0/1)**

Your result strings:

```
abcd 1234 efgh:5678 90ijkl
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I must read more about them... And don't ask a questions like this. =)

Comment: @hiprivet glad to help you. You'd need to write better questions to keep then more accurate because community will get mad. Btw, if my answer answered to your question you may consider marking it as solved :)

Comment: I'm still not clear what question this answers. Are we we talking about editing a URI string?

Comment: @Borodin I think this question is bad formed but what I understood is that OP wanted to remove colons except for port. Btw, as you can see in my answer I put `If your idea is to keep ports` and OP replied `yes`

Comment: I don't understand the comments around. The question is wrong, because didn't show any effort and lacks the precise description, but at the other side, it exactly defines what colons want remove/keep. This answer is satisfied the question, so, don't understand the downvotes...